# Are URL Scheme Suffixes Working in Facebook iOS SDK 3.1?

Tags: facebook, authentication, ios6, url-scheme

I'm trying to update an app of mine to from iOS SDK 3.0 to SDK 3.1, but I'm having issues getting the URL Scheme Suffix to work.  I have a few different SKUs of my app, and have been successfully using scheme suffixes for "ipad" and "iphone" with pre-3.1 SDKs.

When implementing the 3.1 SDK and getting read permissions, the Facebook app no longer sent me back to my app (this is when NOT using the integrated Facebook login in iOS6).  I noticed that if I removed the URL Scheme Suffix, the login process works as intended and I am sent back to my app after saying "OK" to the permissions.  Simply changing the info.plist to not include the suffix makes it work; adding it back breaks it.

My question then: are URL suffixes working for anybody with the 3.1 update?  I haven't been able to get confirmation as to whether they are working or not.  The update does seem to have changed the authentication flow quite a bit, but I can't see why this would be purposely removed.  Also, is this bug on Facebook related? http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/183527235116115

Finally, since I don't feel I can update until this is resolved, what are the consequences of not updating the SDK immediately?  I'd hate for my app to break because the old authentication method is killed.  Does Facebook have a roadmap for when old auth will be unavailable?

Comment: Thanks for the solutions below guys; hopefully, they will be helpful for some people.  It turns out that the issue I was having was a result of a third-party plugin I was using implementing the URL scheme suffixes incorrectly.  Though I was passing the suffix when logging in, the plugin was not using the suffix correctly after updating to Facebook 3.1.  They've fixed it and it is working now.

Comment: You could see a detailed illustration with the updated 2015 version for Xcode 6 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480723/1780492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these things:

- you have an FacebookAppID attribute in your apps' info.plist file
- you have an URL Scheme defined for your app. This scheme has to contain the suffix that you want to use.
- you setup the URL Scheme suffix before calling the FB API.
- the URL Scheme suffix contains only lowercase letters (no special characters like dashes, etc; no spaces)

I was stuck with the last point for about a day!

EDIT: FacebookID in the plist should be called FacebookAppID (type string)

rgds

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you going about creating and opening the session?

I think you must use a two-step approach:

1. initWithAppID:permissions:urlSchemeSuffix:tokenCacheStrategy:
2. openWithCompletionHandler:

I am not sure that this has changed from 3.0 to 3.1 version of the SDK though.